# How to create a pod with cocoapods for local library

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

My source code of a library is in local, not in github or any other network locations. How can I write the `.podspec` file for this case?

Especially, I don't know what to write for `s.source` for a local folder.

I hope after created this local pod, I can use this pod in Podfile:

`pod 'MyLibrary', :path => 'path/to/directory/with/podspec'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the local path to `s.source`, like `s.source = { :git => "/Users/user/Dropbox/Library/UIView+Helper", :tag => "1.0.0" }`

The dependencies must use version control like "git".

Comment: Why was this solution so hard to find? haha Thanks!